# detecting if any BufferedReader is reading from file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I want to know if it is possible to detect any BufferedReader is reading over a file from any other java program which will act as detector for Bufferedreaders.

thanks.

Comment: It is a better idea not to need to know this.  Why do you want this information?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if a `BufferedReader` is reading from a file that other programs are also reading from?  I can't quite parse your question.  Can you add more details and punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't tell if another program is reading a file.  It doesn't matter if the other program is Java or not, or whether the Java program is using a `BufferedReader`.  You can't do it ... unless you implement a ridiculous amount of infrastructure to allow one Java app can dig around in the innards of another one.

As @Peter Lawrey says, you are better of writing your application so that it doesn't need to detect buffering in other applications.

Comment: ok thanks but i want to detect if any BufferedReader or say InputStream is reading over file. any doc over this .

Comment: @RamIndani - *"any doc for this"*.  For what?  For the fact that you can't do it?  I seriously doubt it!  People write documentation for things that you can do, not for things that you can't do.

Comment: @RamIndani - if you told us what you are actually trying to achieve, we could possibly offer you some alternative ways to do it.  But until you do, "YOU CAN'T DO IT" is the best answer we can give.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try to find out other ways to achieve same kind of result like detecting all BUffers reading over file.

Comment: @RamIndani - don't waste your time.  You can't do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to know or prevent it? To prevent you can use a [file lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) (get it via a channel from the stream).

If you just want to know, that is not supported by most operation systems. Normally many processes can read the same file at the same time but only one should write it.

Hmm, but why in hell you need to know that?